# coletar tables de um banco de dados mysql e inserir em outro

Tags: mysql

Olá!
tenho uma duvida, existe uma forma de pegar informações de um banco de dados mysql e inserir em outro com as tables tendo nomes destintos?

exemplo:
quero todas as os inserts do banco 1 tabela nome  e inserir no banco 2 tabela username.

how?

Comment: Se os nomes dos campos da tabela forem iguais, é possível exportar um .csv de uma tabela e importar na outra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturalmente sim! A partir do banco de destino (banco2), você pode fazer assim:

```
INSERT INTO username (coluna1, coluna2)
SELECT coluna1, coluna2
FROM banco1.nome
```

Comment: Muito bom! outra questão: eu poderia pegar registros de uma unica tabela que tem varias colunas distintas e inserir em outra?
exemplo: table1.name e table1.active pra member.name e status.id_active?

Comment: Sim. A aplicação da lógica é a mesma. No `select` você define onde está o valor que você quer pegar e no `insert` você define as colunas para onde esses valores vão. Na mesma sequencia